# How to fix 'Custom Drop Down List' item selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, drop-down-menu

I've used custom Drop-Down list from this website: https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CustomDropDownListStyling/index3.html

I've customised it and used two forms in one page.

Current problem:
1. When two forms are used, selection of one of the form applies to both of them.

Question:
1. How to fix jQuery code so the selection from the Form behaves as an individual without applying it to both of them?
2. Is there any better way how to do custom 'Select Form' rather than with Unordered list and that works on all browsers?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/lukas_kocka/pen/axeeOo

Java Script:

```
function DropDown(el) {
    this.dd = el;
    this.placeholder = this.dd.children('span');
    this.opts = this.dd.find('ul.dropdown > li');
    this.val = '';
    this.index = -1;
    this.initEvents();
}
DropDown.prototype = {
    initEvents: function () {
        var obj = this;

        obj.dd.on('click', function (event) {
            $('.wrapper-dropdown-3').not(this).removeClass('active');
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            return false;
        });

        obj.opts.on('click', function () {
            var opt = $(this);
            obj.val = opt.text();
            obj.index = opt.index();
            obj.placeholder.text(obj.val);
        });
    },
    getValue: function () {
        return this.val;
    },
    getIndex: function () {
        return this.index;
    }
}

$(function () {

    var dd = new DropDown($('.wrapper-dropdown-3'));

    $(document).click(function () {
        // all dropdowns
        $('.wrapper-dropdown-3').removeClass('active');
    });

});
```

I expect both forms to be working as an individual when item is selected.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:
This problem is occurring because both drop-down-list have same id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-3"

I think you can fix it as below:

HTML: Change id of 2nd drop-down-list to "dd1"

```
<div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-3" tabindex="1">
<div id="dd1" class="wrapper-dropdown-3" tabindex="1">
```

js

```
$(function () {

    var dd1 = new DropDown($('#dd1'));
    var dd = new DropDown($('#dd'));

    $(document).click(function () {
        // all dropdowns
        $('.wrapper-dropdown-3').removeClass('active');
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me! Does it mean, if I am going to have 6 of Drop Downs on page I will need to do it separately for every single one?

Comment: Yes, As my knowledge, You need to do it separately for every single one.